# Replace some character by NA data.table

Tags: r, data.table, na

I am building a function to replace some characters like "-" to proper `NA` inside a `data.table` in R.

My function is as follow:

```
na_replacer <- function(data_set, characters_to_replace) {
  text_features <- names(data_set)[sapply(data_set, class) %in% c("character","factor")]
  for (x in text_features) {
    data_set[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, which(x==any(characters_to_replace)), NA))]
  }
  return (data_set)
}
```

When I run this function I am getting the following exception :

> Error in charToDate(x) :
>   character string is not in a standard
>   unambiguous format

Can you please help me get this function working as expected or maybe there is a shorter version to do what I try to perform?

Here is an example dataset with a call to the function

```
DT = data.table(ID = c("foo","bar","-","foo","[]","bah"), a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c = 13:18, d = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "_", "eeee", "ffff"))
DT <- na_replacer(data_set = DT, characters_to_replace = c('-', '_', '[]'))
```

The dataset before:

```
    ID a  b  c    d
1: foo 1  7 13  aaa
2: bar 2  8 14  bbb
3:   - 3  9 15  ccc
4: foo 4 10 16    _
5:  [] 5 11 17 eeee
6: bah 6 12 18 ffff
```

The expected dataset after:

```
    ID a  b  c    d
1: foo 1  7 13  aaa
2: bar 2  8 14  bbb
3:  NA 3  9 15  ccc
4: foo 4 10 16   NA
5:  NA 5 11 17 eeee
6: bah 6 12 18 ffff
```

Comment: Won't this work for you? `gsub('-','NA',df$text)`

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add a [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe I added a verifiable sample with the expected output. I hope this is better; Thanks

Comment: How is this data.table created? If read from file, you may use `fread()` with the parameter `na.strings = c('-', '_', '[]')`.

Comment: Indeed, the data are read from files however I would like to restrict the NA parsing to "character" and "factor". Also, in my pipeline, NA's are introduced as a result of data transformation (not as NA but with others characters). Nonetheless, I will use your suggestion to replace initial NA. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has requested to replace certain character strings in all columns of type `character` or `factor` of a data.table by `NA`.

The [previously accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47137891/3817004) fails for factor columns.

The two approaches below work also for factor columns:

#### Update in join

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)

for (col in DT[, names(.SD)[lapply(.SD, class) %in% c("character", "factor")]]) {
  DT[.(chr = c("-", "_", "[]")), on = paste0(col, "==chr"), (col) := NA_character_][]
}
DT
```

> ```
>        ID     a     b     c      d
>    <char> <int> <int> <int> <fctr>
> 1:    foo     1     7    13    aaa
> 2:    bar     2     8    14    bbb
> 3:     NA     3     9    15    ccc
> 4:    foo     4    10    16     NA
> 5:     NA     5    11    17   eeee
> 6:    bah     6    12    18   ffff
> ```

#### Using `set()`

```
for (col in DT[, names(.SD)[lapply(.SD, class) %in% c("character", "factor")]]) {
  set(DT, DT[get(col) %in% c("-", "_", "[]"), which = TRUE], col, NA_character_)
}
DT
```

> ```
>        ID     a     b     c      d
>    <char> <int> <int> <int> <fctr>
> 1:    foo     1     7    13    aaa
> 2:    bar     2     8    14    bbb
> 3:     NA     3     9    15    ccc
> 4:    foo     4    10    16     NA
> 5:     NA     5    11    17   eeee
> 6:    bah     6    12    18   ffff
> ```

#### Data

The sample data set provided by the OP in the latest update is being used with one modification: Column `d` is coerced to `factor`:

```
DT <- data.table(ID = c("foo", "bar", "-", "foo", "[]", "bah"), 
                 a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c = 13:18, 
                 d = factor(c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "_", "eeee", "ffff")))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant! It is indeed better than the original answer - one question, why are you using "NA_character_" and not simply NA? From a readability point of view, I prefer the `set()` version.

Comment: `NA` is of type logical but the column types are of type `character` and `factor`, resp. One of the advantages of `data.table` is that it updates in place, i.e., without copying the whole column or data object. If selected elements of a column are replaced then the types must match. `data.table` checks this. BTW. I have seen benchmarks where using a numeric constant, e.g. `1`, instead of an integer constant `1L` caused 15%  loss of performance due to type conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Please test this modified function that operates on `data.table`.

```
na_replacer <- function(data_set, characters_to_replace = c('-', '_')) {
    library(data.table)
    setDT(data_set)
    text_features <- names(data_set)[sapply(data_set, class) %in% c("character", "factor")]
    for (x in text_features) {
        foo <- data_set[, get(x)]
        data_set[, eval(x) := ifelse(foo %in% characters_to_replace, NA, foo)]
    }
    return(data_set)
}
```

Comment: @Michael Happy to help :-)

Comment: Sorry, quick question, I see you use `eval()` and `get()` what makes them different?

Comment: @Michael shortly, `get` looks for existing object (in this case column of `data.table`) and `eval` evaluates new expression

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help.

Comment: @Michael you can accept my solution if it solved your problem

Comment: Your solution seems to fail for factor columns.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
solution <- function(dt, replacer) {
  result <- do.call(cbind, lapply(dt, function(x) lapply(x, function(x) {  ifelse(is.na(x), replacer, x) } )))
  as.data.frame(result)
}

# example:
dt <- data.frame(x = c(1, 4, NA, NA, 54), y = c(5, NA, -1, 0, 5))
cat("before:")
dt
cat("after:")
solution(dt, "-")
```

It replace all `NA` values with given sign in data.frame.

Comment: This changes the nature of the class - I want to keep my data.table

Comment: so ya can do `data.table(result)` in the last line of `solution` function.

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this work

```
na_replacer <- function(data_set, characters_to_replace) {
  text_features <- names(data_set)[sapply(data_set, class) %in% c("character","factor")]
  for (x in text_features) {
    data_set[[x]][grep(paste0('[',characters_to_replace,']',collapse  =""),data_set[[x]])] <- NA
  }
  return (data_set)
}
```

Comment: I am getting some warning but I suspect this is not a problem 
> In grep(paste0("[", characters_to_replace, "]"), data_set[[x]]) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Added a parameter to the paste statement please try it again

Comment: I am not sitting by my pc right now maybe  collapse ="*" works better

Comment: This has no effect, the "-" and "_" are still present in the table. I find your code less readable however more powerful (I see other application), would you mind trying to make it working and give some explanation about what the `collapse` is doing?

Comment: if you give paste a vector like yours characters_to_replace it returns a vector as well. In this case if characters_to_replace = c("_","-"). paste0('[',characters_to_replace,']',collapse  ="") returns c("[_]","[-]"). collapse = "" would the reduce this to a string "[_][-]". It would probably be better to first reduce your vector. The code would the look something like this. paste0("[",paste0(characters_to_replace,collapse = ""),"]")